# Mapping values from a dictionary inside MongoDB's aggregate pipeline

Tags: mongodb

I am looking for a way to carry some numeric values (like a probability) along with the keys that I want to $match inside MongoDB's aggregate pipeline, so I can use those values to compute the final aggregates over the matched entries. I wonder if there is a way to implement it with the aggregate pipeline. Can I lookup a key in a supplied dictionary with the $project statement?

Sample document:

```
{
        _id: 'keyword',
        matches: [ { doc_id: 'doc_1', score: 0.5 }, { doc_id: 'doc_2', score: 0.5 } ]
}
```

Sample pipeline:

```
var doc_weights = { 'doc_1': 0.5, 'doc_2': 0.5 };
var doc_ids = ['doc_1', 'doc_2'];
db.keyword_search.aggregate(
    [
        // Find keywords whose search results contain our doc_ids
        { '$match': {
            'matches.doc_id' : { '$in': doc_ids }
        }},

        // Unwind the array of matches containing our doc_ids
        { '$unwind': {
            'path': '$matches',         
        }},

        // Filter out matches with for irrelevant doc_ids
        { '$match': {
            'matches.doc_id' : { '$in': doc_ids }
        }},

        // Weight each match as a product of the match entry score
        // and the document weight
        { '$project': {
            'match_weight':  { '$multiply': [ '$score', doc_weights['$matches.doc_id'] ] },
        }},

        // Compute aggregates 
        { '$group': {
            '_id': '$_id',
            'weight': { '$sum': '$weight' },            
        }},

        { '$limit': 1000 }
    ]
);
```

Comment: It should be possible. Please consider providing an example with sample input and expected output.

Comment: @Veeram, sure. I've added a sample code (not the real one) where I would like to lookup values in the provided dictionary doc_weights.

Comment: Hello,  I have the same question ?
Is there a way to use a global variable  in the pipeline for mapping purpose ?